How to specify ssh config and key for an ansible execution environment?
I'm trying to setup an ansible execution environment and have trouble finding the correct way to specify the ssh config and key to use.
Specifically, I would like to use the following ssh config entry:
Host <host>
  User root
  ProxyCommand /bin/bash -c "ssh -o 'PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa' root@<domain> -W [%h]:%p"
  IdentityFile /runner/.ssh/<keyfile>
  IdentitiesOnly yes

I tried adding the config to the execution environment with these build steps:
additional_build_steps:
  prepend_base:
    - COPY _build/configs/config /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/
    - RUN chmod 700 /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d
    - RUN chmod 600 /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*
    - RUN chown 1000 -R /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d

And then use it in the corresponding inventory:
vars:
  ansible_ssh_common_args: '-F /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/config'
  ansible_ssh_private_key_file: '~/.ssh/<keyfile>'

Which results in the error message
no such identity: /runner/.ssh/<keyfile>: No such file or directory

I think this means that the config was successfully added to the image and is being used, but the keyfile is not being mounted.
I have two questions:

Is this the correct / recommended way to add ssh config to an ansible execution environment?

What would be the correct way to mount / add the required ssh key to the execution environment?



Bumped into the exact same issue too. When i use docker run -it my_ee, i could see all these files are present in the container, but i got the same "no such file" error too. I ended up using "--ll=debug" on ansible-navigator and saw from log file that the wrapper (ansible-navigator wrapping around docker/podman) would mount some directory on default, which got me thinking of using the "--eev" option to mount and it's working in my case.
